# IP Spoofing and AntiForgeryTokens

Tags: web, security

I am trying to determine possible vulnerabilities in a possible site implementation.

We need to be able to determine if the user is logging into the site from an local IP address or external. I know the IP address can be spoofed, though the spoofer won't be able to get much information.

I was thinking it could be possible for a person to spoof a local IP, perform a post action to modify data the server, though this would be difficult (predicting sequence numbers).

If the site used validation tokens on all post request, this might help. In particular I am using .Net MVC 4's AntiForgeryToken. I am not sure how the token is keyed to the user.

My question is if the spoofer went to a page normally to get the token, then spoofed his IP and used the token to do a post, would this succeed?

I know we're getting into the realm of the implausible, but ... Maybe an example might help. Lets say when a user logs in the application detects the IP (not using the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR) and sets the session as local or remote. Could a malicous user load the login screen, get the token, spoof their IP address (assume they are able to determine the sequence number and post), then post the login with that IP address setting them as local?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Phillip

Answer (score 0):

Your site's firewall should block anything with a source IP in your address block, to prevent IP spoofing in the first place.